# sklearn decision_function with 2 or more classes

Tags: python, scikit-learn, svm

I have a model based on [LinearSVC](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.LinearSVC.html#sklearn.svm.LinearSVC.decision_function), and have a variable number of classes. The decision function has a different output for the cases where classes == 2 and classes > 2:

> decision_function(X)
>
> ...
>
> Returns: **array, shape=(n_samples,) if n_classes == 2 else (n_samples, n_classes) :**
>
> Confidence scores per (sample, class) combination. In the binary case, confidence score for self.classes_[1] where >0 means this class would be predicted.

I would like to transform the output in the case of classes == 2 into the same format as in the other cases. But can I just go ahead and mirror the entries at 0?

```
probabilities = model.decision_function(X)
    if len(probabilities[0]) == 1:
        probabilities = [(-p, p) for p in probabilities]
```

From my understanding of SVMs, this should be correct. But sklearn doesn't say anything else about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Negative probabilities don't make sense, what you want is probably `1 - p`. Also, you need to create an `ndarray`, not a list of pairs:

```
prob2 = np.zeros((len(probabilities), 2))
prob2[:,0] = 1 - probabilities
prob2[:,1] = probabilities
```

Comment: I misnamed. The result of decision function is not a list of probabilities, it's a list of distances to the relevant hyperplane. The lists with more than two classes have negative entries as well. Does that change anything?

Comment: @ArneRecknagel: I'm not familiar with the output format of that function for `LinearSVC`, but if this is the definition, then you can just replace `1 - probabilities` by `-probabilities` in my code.